# How to delete a row if first word of 2 cells in that row is a same

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

This has 4000+ entries. I just want to keep the rows where the Property Address is not similar to the Owner Address.

Example:

```
Property Address     Owner Address
4 Belar Street       1 BELAR ST EIGHT MILE PLAINS QLD 4113
30 Bleasby Road      30 BLEASBY RD EIGHT MILE PLAINS QLD 4113
41 Bleasby Road      PO BOX 10326 BRISBANE ADELAIDE STREET QLD 4000
1/41 Bleasby Road    24 GORMANSTON CRES DEAKIN ACT 2600
2/41 Bleasby Road    2/41 BLEASBY RD EIGHT MILE PLAINS QLD 4113
3/41 Bleasby Road    3/41 BLEASBY RD EIGHT MILE PLAINS QLD 4113
4/41 Bleasby Road    PO BOX 5 JANNALI NSW 2226
```

The problem is that the full address is not written in the Property Address column, so how can a formula work? Can there be a formula that compares checks ‘if the first 2 words in both cells in a row are similar’ then deletes that entire row?

Comment: There is a way to simplify this problem. Use the `LEFT()` and `MID` functions to extract the first two words from `property address` and `owner address`. Convert everything to uppercase using `UPPER()`. Compare using `IF()`. If the result is same fill `zero` else fill `1`. Filter out the ones and you have the answer

Comment: @Prasanna Answers should really be placed in the answer area below, not in the comments. That being said, how does your solution handle if the property number is different. Wouldn't that filter our non duplicates?

Comment: @CharlieRB Didn't mean to answer the question really. Just wanted to show directions - that is why I placed it under comments. To answer your question, if the property number is different then it means that the property address and owner address are different. Hence are not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of an answer...

Put this in C2, assuming your table above begins in A1:
`=IFERROR(FIND(UPPER(LEFT(A2;FIND(" ";A2;7)));UPPER(B2));0)`
*Copy down into the remaining cells.*

It takes the straight forward step to search for a second space at or after the 7:th position in the A column. This is of course as a measure to avoid having to deal with "st" and "rd" compared to "street" and "road".
Assuming the position of the second space is found, the portion of the data up till that point is then used as text to find in the second column.

When found, a position number is returned, otherwise (or on errors) a '0' is returned.

*This might be "good enough" to detect similarity.*

The decision to delete needs to be applied by other means.